# System automatically enables guest account

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-accounts

I'm getting in trouble with Windows Server 2008 R2. I disabled guest account, set it to not change the password for security purpose.

After few days, I noticed that the guest account is enabled.

**How can System automatically modify the guest account?**

I reviewed the event log. It shows the following:

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          10/20/2017 11:03:04 PM
Event ID:      4738
Task Category: User Account Management
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A
Computer:      WIN-GQC8F69I8P7
Description:
A user account was changed.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       WIN-GQC8F69I8P7$
    Account Domain:     WORKGROUP
    Logon ID:       0x3e7

Target Account:
    Security ID:        WIN-GQC8F69I8P7\Guest
    Account Name:       Guest
    Account Domain:     WIN-GQC8F69I8P7

Changed Attributes:
    SAM Account Name:   Guest
    Display Name:       <value not set>
    User Principal Name:    -
    Home Directory:     <value not set>
    Home Drive:     <value not set>
    Script Path:        <value not set>
    Profile Path:       <value not set>
    User Workstations:  <value not set>
    Password Last Set:  20/10/2017 11:03:04 CH
    Account Expires:        <never>
    Primary Group ID:   513
    AllowedToDelegateTo:    -
    Old UAC Value:      0x211
    New UAC Value:      0x211
    User Account Control:   -
    User Parameters:    -
    SID History:        -
    Logon Hours:        All

Additional Information:
    Privileges:     -
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" />
    <EventID>4738</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>0</Level>
    <Task>13824</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-10-20T16:03:04.790779000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>10641390</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="488" ThreadID="5744" />
    <Channel>Security</Channel>
    <Computer>WIN-GQC8F69I8P7</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="Dummy">-</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetUserName">Guest</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetDomainName">WIN-GQC8F69I8P7</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetSid">S-1-5-21-1551155493-3377209804-688432216-501</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-5-18</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserName">WIN-GQC8F69I8P7$</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">WORKGROUP</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x3e7</Data>
    <Data Name="PrivilegeList">-</Data>
    <Data Name="SamAccountName">Guest</Data>
    <Data Name="DisplayName">%%1793</Data>
    <Data Name="UserPrincipalName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="HomeDirectory">%%1793</Data>
    <Data Name="HomePath">%%1793</Data>
    <Data Name="ScriptPath">%%1793</Data>
    <Data Name="ProfilePath">%%1793</Data>
    <Data Name="UserWorkstations">%%1793</Data>
    <Data Name="PasswordLastSet">20/10/2017 11:03:04 CH</Data>
    <Data Name="AccountExpires">%%1794</Data>
    <Data Name="PrimaryGroupId">513</Data>
    <Data Name="AllowedToDelegateTo">-</Data>
    <Data Name="OldUacValue">0x211</Data>
    <Data Name="NewUacValue">0x211</Data>
    <Data Name="UserAccountControl">-</Data>
    <Data Name="UserParameters">-</Data>
    <Data Name="SidHistory">-</Data>
    <Data Name="LogonHours">%%1797</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

    Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          10/20/2017 11:03:04 PM
Event ID:      4724
Task Category: User Account Management
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A
Computer:      WIN-GQC8F69I8P7
Description:
An attempt was made to reset an account's password.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       WIN-GQC8F69I8P7$
    Account Domain:     WORKGROUP
    Logon ID:       0x3e7

Target Account:
    Security ID:        WIN-GQC8F69I8P7\Guest
    Account Name:       Guest
    Account Domain:     WIN-GQC8F69I8P7
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" />
    <EventID>4724</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>0</Level>
    <Task>13824</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-10-20T16:03:04.790779000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>10641391</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="488" ThreadID="5744" />
    <Channel>Security</Channel>
    <Computer>WIN-GQC8F69I8P7</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="TargetUserName">Guest</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetDomainName">WIN-GQC8F69I8P7</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetSid">S-1-5-21-1551155493-3377209804-688432216-501</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-5-18</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserName">WIN-GQC8F69I8P7$</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">WORKGROUP</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x3e7</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: how often does this happen?

Comment: Maybe 1 or 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been searching for a couple of days. I realized it happens at the same time every night. I  guessed that it might be a task scheduler then found nothing in Task Scheduler. I used Sysinternals tool and found out the problem. There was a harm VB script in WMI service. Delete it and the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

I would try this, on this system run RSOP.msc then

Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options > Accounts: Guest Account status

it should be Disabled. If it's Enabled then you can see what GPO is applying that policy

Comment: I already set GPO rules as your guide before but it doesn't work. Guest account password is reset and automatically enabled by SYSTEM.